# Check GCC version using Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc

I try to get my gcc version using below code.
when I build and run it ,
console show "Nothing to build fro (my project name) ".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
stringstream version;
version << "GCC version: "
        << __GNUC__ << "." << __GNUC_MINOR__ << "." << __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__
        << "\nVersion string: " << __VERSION__;
cout << version.str() << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `main` function?

Comment: Here is the full code

Comment: You are most likely looking at the wrong console output. Try to find the output of the executable.

Comment: Don't know why it's not working for you, but I could just print __VERSION__ and get the right gcc version eclipse was using.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
I didn't set path variable to MinGW.
I it working properly.
Thank you all.